# Obtaining stored procedure parameter dynamically by name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

Let's create a stored procedure with many similar input parameters with the same type:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SampleStoredProcedure]
    @p1 NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @p2 NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @p3 NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    ...
    @p1000 NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
```

At the beginning, inside the procedure, I want to generate a list of parameters (strings) I should to use, which depends on some database data.

For example, I have 1000 parameters, but I want to read only 10, and execute some SQL statement with these values.

1. Is it possible to get the parameter by its name as string? Any dynamic SQL query?
2. Maybe there is some way to iterate through all input parameters and check if the list contains the current one?

It is possible to generate the SQL with some condition for each parameter separately but the stored procedure will be very long and difficult to modify later. Probably the performance will be worse than in 1. method too. Table Valued Parameter is a solution too, but the point is to avoid it, using separated parameters.

**Summary:**
I have a list of strings defining which input parameters should be mapped and I just want to ignore others, to avoid additional conditions.
The SQL query should be executed only with some input parameters - defined by a context in other table.

Some example:

```
-- It will generate parameters' list - some context.
DECLARE MyCursor CURSOR
    LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
FOR
    SELECT [FieldName] FROM [Fields] AS [F] WHERE [F].[ProjectId] = @ProjectId

-- It will execute some action only for defined input parameters.
OPEN MyCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @FieldName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN 
    -- It doesn't work, but it illustrates the problem.
    SET @FieldValue = N'@' + @FieldName
    EXEC sp_executesql @Query, @Params, @FieldName = @FieldName, @FieldValue = @FieldValue
    FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @Field
END
CLOSE MyCursor
DEALLOCATE MyCursor
```

Comment: what's your goal? why should you be willing to have so many parameters?  is there a requirement? is this a choice you could explain?

Comment: In the core query I need to get value, but dynamically using parameter name.

Comment: you need to get the value using parameter's name: that's the way it works. you recall the parameter by name and then use it. maybe you could show us some code from the procedure and the issues you are facing.

Comment: Your question is so vague there is no way to provide a solid answer. 1,000 parameters screams of very poor design. If you can explain what your procedure needs to do we can help.

Comment: I have some Entity Framework object with many fields. But typically only some fields can contains values for a specified instance, which depends on some discriminator field. So, I am trying to map the EF entity using this stored procedure, but I don't want to map parameters one by one, because the SP will be ugly.

Comment: How do you want to decide which parameters to use?

Comment: You have an EF object with 1,000 properties??? That sounds awful to me. You are going to have to map your parameters one by one. Can you simplify this so you don't have 1,000 properties??

Comment: Of course I can send some array to the SP and maybe it seems like a better design for SP, but it will generate other problems for me. So, the easiest way is just to map Entity Framework object fields one by one to input parameters (it will be generated automatically). So, the point is I need a flat object with many fields. The mapping will be done automatically by EF designer. I need only SP.

Comment: One thing more, I don't want to discuss here about design practices. Just imagine, there is some external constraint where the object must be flat (without any collections). These properties should be mapped to well designed model in a database, but this INSERT/UPDATE stored procedure is a mapper (doing some dirty job in an efficient manner).

Comment: So the question is, if I don't want to use a table valued parameter (many other dirty logic will be needed) is it possible to get an input parameter but its "string name", not by a variable? A collection of parameters to use is different for each request and "stored" in some other table/context.

Answer (score 0):

This will return the name of all parameters for a given Stored Procedure

```
 SELECT
    p.name
    ,p.max_length
FROM
    sys.all_objects o
JOIN
    sys.all_parameters p
ON
    o.object_id = p.object_id
WHERE
    o.name = 'myStoredProcedure'  -- name of stored procedure
```

Comment: Unfortunately I want to use the parameter value inside the procedure. What is more, I know which name to use, but it is not possible to use something like this: SET value = N'@' + @paramName

Comment: @Kryszal, you may consider change your design to Table Valued Parameters from 1000 parameter in stored procedures. Then, it may possible to do the way you want

Comment: Yes, you are right, it will be some solution too. But in this case I cannot use Entity Framework mapping (beetween entity parameters and input parameters of insert/update stored procedure). Eventually, it will be needed to implement some custom logic to process it.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that your parameters(not TVP) have known names(this can be done dynamically using DMVs and Dynamic-SQL), you can use some workaround like:

1) Create Linked Server to itself

2) Query itself using `OPENQUERY`

Your:

```
-- It doesn't work, but it illustrates the problem.
SET @FieldValue = N'@' + @FieldName
```

Will be:

```
SELECT @FieldValue = 
    (SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY('loopback_servername','SELECT ' + @FieldName))
```